# ¿Cómo se debe decir en español? ¿"Un pull request" o "una pull request"?

Tags: anglicismo

Esta es una pregunta que hice en un foro de desarrollo en [stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/615551/c%C3%B3mo-se-debe-decir-en-espa%C3%B1ol-un-pull-request-o-una-pull-request?noredirect=1#comment1083892_615551), ya que pensaba que era adecuado debido a que se da en un contexto de programación:

En mi trabajo estuvimos debatiendo acerca de la pregunta y pensé que podría ser dialogado aquí para saber si existe un consenso de cómo debe escribirse si en femenino o en masculino.

En el inglés no viene siendo un problema, ya que el género realmente no interesa, pero en español cambia debido a que usamos un anglicismo.

¿Se escribe "crear una pull request" o "crear un pull request"?

Pensaba que al tratar de traducirlo podría considerarse como "una solicitud de integración", así que debiese ser femenino, pero al buscar tutoriales y documentación, realmente ya no estoy muy seguro.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: No sabré determinar el género de la frase "pull request", pero he visto preguntas similares en el ámbito de desarrollo. O se usa el anglicismo entero o se usa la alternativa (una solicitud de integración), pero no he visto que mezclen como en "una pull request".

Comment: @Edwar Si quieres decir que has hecho una sola pull request durante el día, ¿cómo puedes hacerlo sin "mezclar"? Si tienes tres arrays ordenados, ¿dices three sorted arrays para no mezclar? No entiendo tu comentario.

Comment: Llevo muchíssimas años traduciendo [hacia el inglés] todo tipo de informática. Lo que pasa es que se traduce algunos términos pero nunca los commandos en un program. Push/pull son commandos. Pero request no lo es exactamente, Se puede traducir perfectamente.

Comment: @Lambie Traduce lo que quieras. ¿"pull-request" es masculino o femenino?

Comment: @RubioRic Ja lo dije: se pone antes: **una** peticion pull: hacer o crear una peticion pull https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request No hyphen IN TEXT

Comment: @RubioRic Al mezclar me refiero a la lógica de usar "una" solo porque la traducción es femenina. A mí suena masculino por el sonido "un pull request".

Comment: @Edwar ¿y eso es lo que querías decir en el anterior comentario? No veo muy bien la relación entre uno y otro pero bueno, como ya digo, no creo que haya una explicación canónica en este caso

Answer (score 3):

Es un problemón. Por lo que parece, la casta no se ha pronunciado aún ni lo va hacer. Porque a cualquier pregunta como estas se responde: ‘Chicos, chicos, el uso de anglicismos es perjudicial para la salud!’; cuando si no fuese por todos estos términos nuevos que le permiten, fundamentalmente a los informáticos, la comunicación en estos ámbitos ni siquiera ellos existirían en la web—la web viene a ser la pólis, por lo tanto: no existir en la web == no existir.

Entonces, centrémonos en lo que sí importa. En vista de que no veo que sea muy utilizada la traducción al castellano y podría incluso ser confusa (un pusheo también sería una especie de integración, etc etc.), te sugiero leer [este artículo](http://rua.ua.es/dspace/bitstream/10045/93912/1/2019_Felix-Rodriguez_BRAE.pdf). Allí (p. 354) el autor rescata una serie de factores que parecen ser los más influyentes, aunque remarca que no hay una regla decisiva:

- homografía, que no la hay en nuestro caso
- homofonía: el tEST --> EL requEST, punto para el masculino
- analogía: este punto depende, porque para quien piense que ‘request’ es ‘LA solicitud’ será ‘LA request’; mientras que quien lo asocie con ‘EL pedido’ pensará en ‘EL request’
- núcleo elidido por elipsis: no hay ninguna elipsis
- género no marcado: que por lo que entiendo viene dado por ciertas categorías de palabras, por ejemplo, todos los géneros musicales son masculinos, etc etc. y tampoco aplicaría

De todos los puntos, yo creo que el decisivo es el tercero. Para mí, ‘request’ es ‘pedido’; siempre dije ‘**el** pull request’ y es lo que escuché en todo mi ámbito. Por lo tanto, es lo que recomendaría. Pero no veo tampco que por el momento haya una respuesta decisiva, y para el día en que la tengamos ya va a haber desaparecido Git. Saludos.

Comment: request es una petición, no un pedido en informática: Definición de petición (computación)
Significado de petición: En un modelo cliente-servidor, una petición es un requerimiento o solicitud que le hace un cliente a un servidor.

Fuente: https://www.alegsa.com.ar

Comment: @Lambie es lo mismo, te lo va a decir cualquiera con dos dedos de frente

Comment: Pues bien no es un problemón. Los tíos que escriben sobre estos temas no tienen ningún problema.

Answer (score 2):

Como indica Tac, ninguna autoridad se ha pronunciado. Es más, desconozco si existe tal autoridad universalmente reconocida en el mundo de la ingeniería software hispanohablante.

En mi entorno (Málaga, España) lo usamos en másculino, ya que ese es el que empleamos para los comandos del git. Nosotros ejecutamos un comando, ya sea push, pull, merge, ...; por tanto decimos hacer un push, hacer un merge, etc. Aunque un pull request no es un comando, por asociación empleamos generalmente también el másculino. Al iniciar un pull request, podríamos decir que se inicia un proceso de revisión, para intentar justificar ese uso masculino, pero creo que la explicación no es otra que la asimilación que indico a los comandos.

Señalo lo que usamos mis colegas y yo, pero no considero inválido que se diga una pull request, si para vosotros lo que prima es la petición, que es la palabra más extendida como traducción de request y que le da el género femenino.

Saliendonos del ámbito informático y de los anglicismos, todavía me suena raro oir un sartén en algunos videos procedentes de Latinoamérica cuando en España es una sartén. Y ya pueden decir lo que quieran en la RAE, ambos usos son perféctamente válidos.

No he entendido el comentario de Edwar de no mezclar. Al emplear directamente un sustantivo tomado del inglés SIEMPRE lo acompañamos de un determinante en español, que SIEMPRE tiene género: un array, un cd, una request, ... Al igual que podemos calificarlo con un adjetivo: un array desordenado, un cd rayado, una pull request enviada, un merge ejecutado ...

Comment: Las autoridades en estos casos son los que escriben sobre el tema. una request me suena muy mal.

Comment: You even say: hacer un push. Pues entonces, se podria decir perfectamente hacer una petición push. I don't see how you can tell me that my answer no tiene nada que ver. Tiene todo que ver. Cuando se dice una petitición, lo de el o la desaparece.

Comment: A ver, yo he comentado cómo lo usamos mis compañeros y yo. Cualquiera que escriba sobre el tema y cuelgue un artículo en internet no es una autoridad. Y menos es una autoridad en cómo tenemos que usar el español mezclado con inglés los profesionales.

Comment: There is only writing about IT but Spanish-speaking IT professionals, who, in effect, become the autoridades. You are not responding to my actual argument: some things are translated, others aren't. Push/pull are commands. They are not usually translated; they are kept in English. The articles I cited are good ones.

Comment: Lo de que los comandos de git no se traducen ya lo he indicado. OP pregunta que si "pull-request" es masculino o femenino. Lo que has pegado no es ninguna autoridad, no es ninguna institución reconocida, no es ninguna personalidad importante de la programación, y no se detiene a discutir esa cuestión sobre el genero de ese término. Es un manual de git en español cogido de internet.

Comment: No es con hifen. El término es una petición o un requeirimiento o una solicitud Pull. Igual que GET, POST, PUSH, etc.

Comment: @Lambie Es increíble como, teniendo y sabiendo que existen millones de formas de pensar la palabra request (pedido, por ejemplo), y sabiendo que no suele ir traducido, y que eso es lo que da pie a la pregunta del OP sobre cuál es el género correcto; sabiendo que no tenés idea de nada de todo esto y que de pedo sabés escribir las tildes; que lo único que te interesa es ganar en el arte de la erística porque de otra forma tu discurso no puede mapear con la realidad; sabiendo todo eso te da la cara para seguir viniendo a responder?

Comment: @Lambie Parece que vamos a tener que empezar a considerarte una planta por no ser capaz de producir un discurso que sea significativo y que tenga una cuota mínima de sentido

Answer (score 0):

Los ejemplos abajo los pusé para el lenguaje PULL y petición [request].

Por lo general en arquitecturas:

> **El modelo PULL** En el modelo denominado PULL, el cliente es quien inicia la comunicación con el servidor, es decir, es el cliente quien
> *requiere* [requests] la información y el servidor contesta. Los clientes son quienes consultan los datos cuando los necesitan, el
> servidor se limita a suministrarlos en el momento y en ningún otro.
>
> Los servidores en este tipo de arquitectura están a la espera de que
> los clientes necesiten sus datos actualizados, estas peticiones pueden
> ser requeridas por un usuario o estar programadas en un cliente, que
> actualiza la información en intervalos de tiempo predefinidos.
>
> Los receptores de la comunicación puede analizar (y generalmente lo
> hace) la reputación del servidor, y también gestiona el interés del
> contenido emitido, puede contemplarlo o descartarlo, es decir, es el
> cliente quien controla lo que le interesa de toda la información
> recibida.

Por ejemplo, podemos definir una búsqueda en un servidor como una petición PULL [...]
[PULL en la arquitectura](https://iberasync.es/comunicacion-basada-en-push-y-pull-en-arquitecturas-cliente-servidor/)

hacer una petición PULL, hacer una búsqueda en un servidor como una petición PULL

[Aqui: GITHUB]

> En esta entrada, la tercera de una serie de tres, explicamos qué es un
> pull request y cómo funciona en github.
>
> ¿Qué es un pull request? Un pull request es una **petición** que el
> propietario de un fork de un repositorio hace al propietario del
> repositorio original para que este último incorpore los commits que
> están en el fork. En el caso que nos ocupa, el usuario
> aprendegit-user1 le enviará la petición [request] a aalbagarcia para que este
> último incorpore los commits que tiene en su fork.
>
> Lo primero que hará el usuario aprendegit-user1 será crear una rama
> que apuntará al último commit que ha hecho y que contiene las
> modificaciones a la página de inicio. El procedimiento es el de
> siempre: [ver la página]

[**hacer una petición pull**](https://aprendegit.com/que-es-un-pull-request/)

Tambien:

> Qué es un pull request? Una *solicitud de extracción* o pull request,
> a menudo abreviado como PR, es una característica de los sistemas de
> control de versiones como Git. Significa una solicitud para fusionar
> código de una rama a otra, normalmente de la rama personal del
> desarrollador a una rama principal o de desarrollo.

[solicitud de extracción](https://www.techopedia.com/es/definicion/pull-request)

Pregunta: **Se escribe "crear una pull request" o "crear un pull request"?**

Respuesta: **algunos términos suelen ser traducidos, otros no**.
Como push/pull o PUSH/PULL son commandos en programas, no se traducen porque el programa no funcionaria.

Definición de petición (computación) Significado de petición: En un modelo cliente-servidor, una petición es un requerimiento o solicitud que le hace un cliente a un servidor. Fuente: alegsa.com.ar –

**Traducción: una petición o un requerimiento o una solicitud PULL.**

No hay razón para no traducir request.

Comment: La primera parte no tiene que ver con la segunda aunque ambas empleen la palabras pull y request y estén relacionadas con el software. OP no está preguntando qué es un modelo cliente-servidor con pull, ni qué es un pull-request en git. El texto citado entra en contradicción consigo mismo: "UN pull request es UNA petición". Si es UNA petición, ¿porqué no es UNA pull request?

Comment: @RubioRic Okay, this is easier for me in English. A request over the internet or to a database is a PULL [or PUSH] request.  The only part that is translated is the word request, una petición. So why not translate the translateable part and not the word PULL, which is not translated?? Estaba postando estes dos ejemplos para el lenguaje PULL. La informática en otros idiomas traducen algunas cosas y otras no. PULL no se traduce y request sí, se traduce.

Comment: @Lambie Eso no tiene nada que ver con lo que está preguntando el OP

Comment: @RubioRic Of course it does. The entire thing is about translation. If you say una petitición PULL, there is no reason NOT to say: hacer una petitición pull. First you say I was not in the right context, now you say what I said does not concern the question. The point is to **look at existing IT writing in Spanish** and come up with a good expression. There is already a tradition in IT where some terms are translated, others not. There are no autoridades here. There are basically IT guys writing about these things. Some better and some worse.

Comment: No entiendo el proposito de tu respuesta y me pierdo en tus comentarios. Se llama "pull-request" por que así lo llama github. OP intenta saber si es másculino o femenino ese sustantivo. Todo lo que has puesto del modelo servidor-cliente mediante pull NO tiene nada que ver. Si en tu trabajo tú usas "petición pull", estupendo, indica eso en lugar de todos esos textos copypasteados.

Comment: There is ONLY one meaning of Pull in networks, databases etc. pull:
Frequently used to describe data sent over the Internet; the act of requesting data from another computer. Contrast to "push" technology when data is sent to you without a specific request being made. https://www.dataprise.com/it-glossary/ In GitHub: the act of requesting data from another computer (or repository or fork). I don't translate into Spanish, only INTO English. I learned IT usage from READING Spanish IT writers.

Comment: I only copypasted TWO texts to show the usage. And I even explained why.